# Array formula returning some dates and some whole numbers

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets and I am importing a column of dates from one sheet to the other based on values in the first column

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    VLOOKUP($A$2:$A,Sheet2!$A:$N,
        MATCH(M$1,Sheet2!$1:$1, 0), True
     )
 )
```

This works fine however when it imports the data I get some as dates (what I want) and some as whole numbers:

```
DATE
43016
42982
42772
16/07/2017
42927
30/11/2017
28/12/2017
28/12/2017
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also, you can force dates with `TO_DATE`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(
 VLOOKUP($A$2:$A, Sheet2!$A:$N,
 MATCH(M$1, Sheet2!$1:$1, 0), 1)))
```

Comment: I hadn't seen TO_ operator before. That has it solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will need to format them with:

[image]